# Mailgun: send emails if recipient does not have tag

Tags: python, python-requests, mailgun

I use Mailgun to send emails for my businesses and I've been struggling to find a way to send emails to certain recipients that do not have a specific tag. I've tried using the events api to see if can grab a list of all recipients that have certain tags using this:

```
def get_logs():
return requests.get(
    "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/events",
    auth=("api", "YOUR_API_KEY"),
    params={"tags": "indoctrination"})
```

However this does not work because the api will not pull more than 100 records per call.

I've also tried other variation of this where I will create a new mailing list and use that to try to track my campaigns instead of using tags but again I run into the 100 record limit.

All I need to do here is send an email to my list based on what tags they have or don't have. It doesn't seem like it should be this complicated. Is there a better way of doing list segmentation?

The Mailgun documentation is [available here](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api_reference.html).